# Can we use elastic search as a cache for fast retrieval of data?

Tags: caching, elasticsearch, nosql

I want to build a system that will have to have to answer queries in real time. I would have to update data every 1 hour and would have to add about a million documents. Can we use elastic search for this or should I go with nosql?

Answer (score 15):

using elasticsearch as a cache is fair.You can easily maintain it as cache layer on your primary storage.

1)But keep an eye on your reindexing strategy.When you will be adding 1 million documents to cluster every hour it will be very heavy operation on your hardware in terms of disk I/O.

2)Also keep an eye on  concurrency issue while doing bulk indexing to the cluster to tune it to optimum value by varying bulk size document, threadpool and queue size.default value of queue size for bulk indexing is 50.

[Threadpool elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-threadpool.html)

Also what is your cluster architecture - Number of nodes, replicas, shards

Answer (score 4):

I think it's a very good idea to use Elasticsearch to search/display datas, you can save any data you like as any format.

You can read this article for more details : [Uses of Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-uses-of-elasticsearch)

What kind of technology want you use to connect your datas into Elasticsearch ?

Good luck :)

Comment: ummm....  datas?